# How can I find an associated table oldest record filtering by one of it's attributes?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql

I have the model `Subscription` which `has_many` `Version`s.

A `Version` has a `status`, `plan_id` and `authorized_at` date.

Any changes made to a `Subscription` comes from a `Version` modifications updating it's parent `Subscription`.

The goal is to find each Subscription's `Version` with the oldest `authorized_at` date `WHERE` the `versions.plan_id` is the same as the `subscriptions.plan_id` (in other words I need the authorization date of the `Version` where the `plan_id` changed to the current `Subscription`'s `plan_id`).

This is the query I've come up with. I'm getting an error in the aggregate function syntax:

```
syntax error at or near "MIN" LINE 3: MIN (authorized_at) from versions ^
```

query:

```
select subscriptions.id,
MIN (authorized_at) from versions
where versions.plan_id = subscriptions.plan_id
) as current_version
from subscriptions
join versions on subscriptions.id = versions.subscription_id
where versions.status = 'processed'
```

I also am not sure if I should be grouping the versions by `plan_id` and then picking from each group. I'm kind of lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [lateral subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) which can best be described as a foreach loop in SQL. They are an extremly performant way to select columns from a single correlated record or even aggregates from a group of related records.

For each row in subscriptions the DB will select a single row from versions ordered by authorized_at:

```
SELECT "subscriptions".*,
       "latest_version"."authorized_at" AS current_version,
       "latest_version"."id" AS current_version_id -- could be very useful
FROM   "subscriptions" 
LATERAL
  (
     SELECT   "versions"."authorized_at", "versions"."id"
     FROM     "versions"
     WHERE    "versions"."subscription_id" = "subscriptions"."id" -- lateral reference
     AND      "versions"."plan_id" = "subscriptions"."plan_id"
     AND      "versions"."status" = 'processed'
     ORDER BY "versions"."authorized_at" ASC
     LIMIT 1
  ) latest_version ON TRUE
```

Creating lateral joins in ActiveRecord can be done either with SQL strings or Arel:

```
class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  # Performs a lateral join and selects the 
  # authorized_at of the latest version 
  def self.with_current_version
    lateral = Version.arel_table.then do |v|
      v.project(
        v[:authorized_at],
        v[:id] # optional
      ).where(
        v[:subscription_id].eq(arel_table[:id])
          .and(v[:plan_id].eq(arel_table[:plan_id]) )
          .and(v[:status].eq('processed'))
      )
      .order(v[:authorized_at].asc)
      .take(1) # limit 1
      .lateral('latest_version ON TRUE')
    end
    lv = Arel::Table.new(:latest_version) # just a table alias
    select(
      *where(nil).arel.projections, # selects everything previously selected
      lv[:authorized_at].as("current_version"),
      lv[:id].as("current_version_id") # optional
    ).joins(lateral.to_sql)
  end
end
```

If you just want to select the `id` and `current_version` column you should consider using pluck instead of selecting database models that aren't properly hydrated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DISTINCT ON` to filter out rows, and keep a single one per subscription -- the first one per group according to the `ORDER BY` clause.

For example:

```
select distinct on (s.id) s.id, v.authorized_at
from subscription s
join versions v on v.subscription_id = s.id and v.plan_id = s.plan_id
where v.status = 'processed'
order by s.id, v.authorized_at
```

Comment: Thank you. The query seems to work in console, but when I try to use it in my views as a model scope I get `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"
LINE 6: ...s.id, v.authorized_at WHERE "sub...`

Comment: @pinkfloyd90 I'm no expert on ActiveRecord, but maybe it doesn't work because the view is probably not updatable.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will give you the `versions` where Version's `plan_id` is equal to Subscription's `plan_id`.

```
@versions = Version.joins("LEFT JOIN subscriptions ON subscriptions.plan_id = versions.plan_id")
```

To filter records by Version's `status`

```
@versions = Version.joins("LEFT JOIN subscriptions ON subscriptions.plan_id = versions.plan_id").where(status: "processed")
```

To filter records by Version's `status` and order by `authorized_at` in ascending order.

```
@versions = Version.joins("LEFT JOIN subscriptions ON subscriptions.plan_id = versions.plan_id").where(status: "processed").order(:authorized_at)
```

To filter records by Version's `status` and order by `authorized_at` in decending order.

```
@versions = Version.joins("LEFT JOIN subscriptions ON subscriptions.plan_id = versions.plan_id").where(status: "processed").order(authorized_at: :desc)
```

Hope this works for you!

Comment: I think you need to join on `subscriptions.id = versions.subscription_id` or you will get versions in that result that don't belong to that subscription. You also haven't even touched on the core of the question which is selecting an aggregate.